# Stop Eclipse-Kepler from showing live preview of html pages

Tags: html, eclipse, jsp, eclipse-kepler

Does any one know how to close the live preview of html pages?

in Kepler version of eclipse,
 
 when i open a html page or a jsp page,
 
 it displays the live preview alongside my code in Design tab.

This reduces my system performance and Eclipse starts Not Responding.

After few hours of working, eclipse keeps on displaying some random errors,

1. Null pointer Reference
2. No more handlers (and few more)

Is there a way to stop eclipse-kepler from displaying the live preview of html pages??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to change the editor associated with html files. You can do it ad-hoc in the contextual menu of the file "Open With" and choose other editor

In a permanent way:
Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File associations